# Is the Einstein A coefficient the same as the natural line width $\Gamma$?

Tags: atomic-physics, two-level-system

Given a two-level system, the rate of decay from the excited state via spontaneous emission is given by the coefficient $A$ in Einstein's rate equations. However, there is also the natural line width $\Gamma$ (usually given in MHz$\times 2 \pi$) which can be experimentally obtained from spectroscopy experiments. The $\Gamma$ is related to the lifetime of the excited state by $\tau = 1/\Gamma$. Is $A = \Gamma$ or is it off by a factor of $2\pi$?

Take, e.g. the D2 line of $^{87}$Rb. Here, $\Gamma = 6$MHz $ \times 2 \pi$, correspondingly $\tau = 26$ns. Is $A = 6$MHz or $A = 6$MHz $ \times 2 \pi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refer you to page 176 of Daniel Steck's [*Quantum and Atom Optics* notes](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOudXC_e7RAhWBVLwKHQqFAEoQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fatomoptics-nas.uoregon.edu%2F%7Edsteck%2Fteaching%2Fquantum-optics%2Fquantum-optics-notes.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHsPzx_H6cB1ce-ePOnYoUlumYe3g&sig2=Dki4oskjTpy-1HFrLuHpzA)

> We thus identify $\Gamma = A_{21}$ as the excited-state decay rate.

where $A_{21}$ was previously defined as the Einstein coefficient.